# How to use eslint rule react-hooks/exhaustive-deps to warn about violations in point free function expressions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

In my `.eslintrc` I've configured the rule `"react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "error"`.

The linter seems to fail to warn about missing deps when hooks are used in a point free style. Here's a minimal example:

```
const always = input => () => input;
const useDemonstration = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const getValue = useCallback(always(value), []);
  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(previousValue => previousValue + 1);
  }, []);
  return getValue;
};
```

The above code violates the exhaustive deps rule: `getValue` is missing dependency `value` but the linter emits no errors.

I already know I can change `always(value)` to `() => always(value)()` to get the linter working again. I'm looking for a solution that wouldn't require changing the code I've written to get lint errors.

Whether this is intended behaviour or not **I would like to have my linter error in cases like the example**. Is there a linter rule or a workaround to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, ESlint is a **syntax analyzer**, therefore it doesn't aware of the semantics ("`always` returns a function").

For getting the desired behavior you need [semantic analysis](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Semantic_analysis_(compilers)) by introducing types-system like **Flow** & **Typescript**.

[image]